# Is dajjal mentioned in the Quran?

Tags: quran, day-of-judgement, dajjal

If dajjal is a very important warning sign in the end days, does the quran mention his name or about him? Please provide proof only if it is available in the quran. Thank you :)

Comment: If we say no he isn't mentioned how can we give a proof for that?

Comment: I need proof only if it is there in the quran, give me the chapter and verse number :3 im currently in chapter 63, just wanted to know if a verse is available about dajjal.

Comment: If its not availbale just simlpy say no and ill select it as a correct answer

Comment: Dajjal is not mentioned. Some people derive certain implications from some verses but that’s not concrete and simply interpretive.

Comment: I believe, there is a hadith which mentions the Dajjal being a very insignificant creation (even though he has been warned about). That might explain his absence in the Quran. [Muslim 7020] Mughira b. Shu'ba reported: No one asked Messenger of Allah ﷺ more about Dajjil than I asked him. He said: He should not be a source of worry to you for he would not be able to do any harm to you. I said: Allah's Messenger, it is alleged that he would have along with him (abundance of) food and water. Thereupon he said: He would be very insignificant in the eye of Allah (even) with all this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad-Dajjal has not been (clearly) mentioned in the Quran for some possible reasons: Maybe because he is one of the worst creatures and to show his low value he was not even mentioned to show this dispraise. On the other hand Pharao was mentioned because his lies (such as [28:38](http://legacy.quran.com/28/38) and [79:24](http://legacy.quran.com/79/24)) have been clearly shown off, while ad-Dajjal's lies can only come to light when the real "Messiah" 'Issa returns and make an end to his reign.

Therefore when mentioning 'Issa's return in the Quran one can conclude a hint of the Dajjal such as in the verses [4:157-159](http://legacy.quran.com/4/157-159) which clearly says that 'Issa has neither been killed nor crucified, before confirming that any of the people of the book would believe in him (the real Messiah 'Issa) before his death, so this verse say he will come back and then people who knew the scripture would recognize and believe him and reject ad-Dajjal.

Also this verse is used as a hint of ad-Dajjal:

> ... The Day that some of the signs of your Lord will come no soul will benefit from its faith as long as it had not believed before or had earned through its faith some good. ... ([6:158](http://legacy.quran.com/6/158))

Based on the hadith mentioned in sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:158), Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/740770) and sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/92/68):

> "There are three, for which when they appear, a soul will not benefit by its faith, if it did not believe before the Signs: Ad-Dajjal, the Beast, and the rising of the sun from its setting place" - or "from the west."

However there are scholars who don't believe in the coming of ad-Dajjal:
[Muhammad 'Abduh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Abduh) has interpreted ad-Dajjal as meaning legends, charlatanism and quackery based on the words of [Muhammad Rashid Rida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashid_Rida) the author of tafsir al-Manar.

> الشيخ محمد عبده وقال:الدجال هو كناية عن الخرافات والدجل والشعوذة

Muhammad Faheem abu 'Obaydah: in his commentary of a book of ibn Kathir interpreted ad-Dajjal as meaning: the outbreak of corruption and evil.

> محمد فهيم أبو عبيدة: في تعليقه على أحاديث الدجال في الكتاب الملاحم لابن كثيرقال:{ هذا انتشار الفساد والشر}

Comment: @Envayo and what does it say according you then?

Comment: @Envayo a logical approach: If any of the people of the book would believe or follow 'Isa before his death we have two possibilities: "his death" refers to any of the people of the book, this can't be the case as this isn't true (Jews still reject 'Isa's prophethood), if it is 'Isa's death then that would mean 'Isa must die, for this he must be among us again. There's a small chance that this still refers to the people of the book at the end of the time, but this is really far-fetched!

Comment: In the tafsir of zamakhsari this is also mentioned : "والمعنى: وما من اليهود والنصارى أحد إلا ليؤمننّ قبل موته بعيسى".. There have been different of opinions on exactly who is intended in the word "mawtihi". Many mean it to be Jesus while some mean it is the one   from ahlu kitab . *(I've heard one interpreting it to be the Prophet Muhamed. I.e "some of the people of the scripture will believe in jesus before the Prophet Mohammeds death.")*

Answer (score 0):

No Dajjal is not mentioned in the Holy Quran ... it is an Arabic form for Anti-Christ ... the idea was adopted by the eschatological traditions of Sufism and was the result of newly converties from Christians to Islam.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. we require answers here to be well elaborated, focused on answering the actual question and claims to be supported by evidences (see [answer]). As is this looks more likely like a comment with an unproved claim.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamualaikum, Alhamdulillah, 
I had watched many lectures from Sheikh Imran N. Hosein.

Well, according to Sheikh Imran N. Hosein, the word Jasad in the ayat below refers to Dajjal. It's indeed a direct quote of him as it is a snapshot of his ebook "Dajjal The Quran and Awwal al Zaman".

He has actually found Dajjal in the Quran even the word was not specifically stated "Dajjal" there. As he said, but he could be wrong and Allah SWT know the best.
You can search his lecture about Dajjal on YouTube because his lecture usually around 1 hour and plus.

You can buy and download his book and ebook about Dajjal in the Quran at :http://imranhosein.org/books/571-dajjal-the-quran-and-awwal-al-zaman.html![image]

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. The opinion of a single person not substantiated by opinions of scholars over the centuries is not considered evidence.

Comment: Would it be possible to be more specific as to what Sheikh Imran N. Hosein says (i.e., quote him directly)?

Comment: Well, according to Sheikh Imran N. Hosein, the word Jasad in the ayat above refers to Dajjal. It's indeed a direct quote of him as it is from his ebook "Dajjal The Quran and Awwal al Zaman".

Comment: To III-AK-III, it's not but he is the FIRST scholar ever to found Dajjal in The Quran. This is a new finding of the ayat so the scholars over the centuries had not made a tafsir as convincing as this one from him.

Comment: This is not the only new finding in the Quran, there's a lot more from him. Sheikh Imran N. Hosein is indeed a chosen people by Allah to have Nur(light) to understand the mystic facts of the Quran and Hadith about The Akhirul Zaman(End of History).As he is a philosopher specializing in the Islamic estacology, please watch his lectures and read his books.

Comment: And I'm advising all of us, don't just accepting some short answers on the Net, make your OWN research too. That's why I put the link to his book at his website so we can read his books and understand the subject better.

Answer (score -2):

How did this become sunnah to seek protection from dijall ! Because i agree with the people who say is a hoax . allah clearly says" there is none like him" he allah swa  ask a qustion in quran also something like. "in wich hadith will u rely on next " meaning that is Quran is the only hadith authentic , the prophets lifestyles had mistakes and and emotions like all human being . the prophet noah preached about dijjall and rasul joked about dijjall true indeed but rasul lu lah saw  also asked allah for forgiveness from his mistakes and his sence of humor and plain out asked for forgiveness of innovation. The first book of hadis  was granted to the prophet saw . people who say he was walking quran must understand that was not literal . the rasul says to follow bilal raw. Because he is a successor and for the ulima to imulate him becaus. , he the rasul saw. was insecure on reaching jinna the proof is there. !!!!!!!! but i think what has happened is that instead of worship to allah ; some send worship  to muhammed so........ my example is when tne rasul died bilal  raw. Did not want to call tbe ahdan and when he did offer the ahdan  the people cried so hard bilal left 
Bilal raw. says this when the prophet died ,"Whoever worships Muhammad (pbuh) should know that Muhammad (pbuh) died. Whoever worships Allah should know that Allah is Hayy (immortal).”[3]

Then, he recited the following verse:

“Muhammad is no more than a Messenger: many were the Messengers that passed away before Him. If he died or was slain, will ye then turn back on your heels? If any did turn back on his heels, not the least harm will he do to Allah; but Allah (on the other hand) will swiftly reward those who (serve him) with gratitude”[4]

Naaaa uuum

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].